# I can't connect to django in a Docker container (but doing the same thing works for Apache)

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, python, docker, django

I have been going around and around trying to run a simple Django application in a container and then access it from a browser.  I googled and read dozens of postings explaining how to to do it and could not see the difference, so I tried doing the same thing using Apache and it works beautifully using Apache.  Now I have a container that runs both and I can get to the simple Apache server, but not the Django server.  The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3.5
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN alias python=python3.5
RUN echo "alias python=python3.5" >> /root/.bashrc
RUN apt-get install -y vim
RUN pip3 install django

RUN django-admin startproject HelloDjango
RUN cd /HelloDjango
RUN python3.5 /HelloDjango/manage.py makemigrations
RUN python3.5 /HelloDjango/manage.py migrate
RUN apt-get install -y lynx

COPY runscr /HelloDjango/runscr
COPY settings.py /HelloDjango/HelloDjango/settings.py
EXPOSE 81

RUN apt-get install -y apache2
COPY html/* /var/www/html/
WORKDIR /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
```

Then I start the container by:

> docker run -it -p 1234:81 -p 1235:80 mydjango /bin/bash

Once in the container, I run:

```
python3.5 /HelloDjango/manage.py runserver 81 &
apachectl -D FOREGROUND &
```

and then I test from inside the container using lynx:

```
lynx http://127.0.0.1:81/
lynx http://127.0.0.1:80/
```

and I see what I ought to see in both cases.  The problem comes when I try to get to these from a browser.  The URLs that I go to are

hostIP:1235

which gives me my simple page served by Apache and

hostIP:1234

which says "Unable to connect"  I get the same results using Firefox, IE, Chrome, and Edge.  I have also swapped 80 and 81 between Django and Apache.

What is so different between Django and Apache that the same steps taken to bind the ports work for Apache and not for Django?

Any suggestions will be appreciated and any requests for additional information will be promptly served.